# Using Javascript to get the URL works in firefox but not android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, getelementsbyclassname

I've tested my javascript code in firebug and it works.  However, when I use the exact same code in my android app, it does nothing.

I'm trying to make an app which can get the link information for the previous and next pages on a web site to navigate a webview.  Here's what I have:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:{ var child = document.getElementsByClassName('navi navi-prev')[0].href;" +
            "document.location.href=child;}");
```

The relevant HTML segment is below.

```
<div id="comic-foot"><div id="sidebar-undercomic" class="customsidebar ">

<div class="comic_navi_wrapper">
    <table class="comic_navi">
    <tr>
    <td class="comic_navi_left">
    <a href="..." class="navi navi-first" title="First">First</a>
    <a href="...(this is the link I'm trying to get)..." class="navi navi-prev" title="Previous">Previous</a>
```

Currently, the javascript doesn't do anything.  It just stays on the webview and doesn't change when I activate it (I have a button for now).  Like I said, the code works in firefox, so I'm not sure what changes need to be made to accommodate the built-in android browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  The code does work correctly. After a day or so of messing with the code and blaming browser differences, I realized it was a stupid mistake with the onLoadResource method. Every time it would start to load the new code, the onLoadResource method would intialize and set the webView back to the same point, making the code appear to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The `history` object is part of `window` object. It holds all the urls that are navigated so far in a browser window.
Per my understanding , history object is not application specific but rather browser specific i.e. it is not created per application but rather created when the browser starts and gets destroyed when the browser is closed.

Also, there is no method in the history object that would give back the pages visited, though there is a method that says how many urls are visited so far (`length` method)

If the requirement is to show the pages that a user visited in an application, during his session in the application, then I suggest using the `session` object itself to hold the pages that the user visited and then show links to these pages as next/previous.
Also with this you will have more control over the page navigation.